# Fixed div disappearing in portrait orientation only on Firefox and Android Browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

This is my first post, sorry in advance for editing mistakes!

I'm working on a page that is just a bunch of pictures and a hidden menu that slides in at a button press. It's just a fixed div that I kept outside the screen, then I animate the 'right' property with jQuery to move the div into view when the icon is clicked. It's working as intended when I tested in Chrome (both desktop and mobile versions) and the desktop version of Firefox.

So I tested the mobile version of Firefox and it works normally when the phone is in landscape mode, but in portrait mode the menu doesn't even show up! The icon animates as normal but the div is nowhere to be found. The same thing happens when using the default Android browser.

I tried setting the display to 'block' right away and adjusting the position to set the div right in the middle of the screen, I could see the div just fine in landscape mode but nothing in portrait mode. The weird thing is that in the responsive mode on desktop Firefox everything works fine, the problem is really
only when using the mobile version.

I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm also using Bootstrap 4 for the grid, Google Fonts and Fontawesome.io for the icon. Here's the code, and thanks for reading!

edit: You can see a working example on this page https://joaoandreossi.github.io/

## HTML

```
<head>
   ...
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
   ...
</head>

<body>
   ...
   <div class="container-fluid row">        
    <div class="col-sm-4 image-div">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 image-div">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 image-div">
        ...
    </div>
   </div>

  <i class="fa fa-angle-left menu-arrow"></i>

  <div class="menu-slide">
    <a href="../index.html"><p class="menu-item">Início</p></a>
    <a href=""><p class="menu-item" style="color:white">Trabalhos</p></a>
    <a href="../contato/contato.html"><p class="menu-item">Contato</p></a>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

## CSS

```
.menu-slide{
   position: fixed;
   right: -40vw;
   height: 100vh;
   padding-top: 25vh;
   background-color: #000;
   text-align: right;
   display: none;
}

.menu-item{
   color: gray;
   font-size: 25px;
   margin: 10px 20px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed',sans-serif;
}

.menu-arrow{
   color: white;
   font-size: 50px;
   right: 0;
   top: 45vh;
   position: fixed;
   margin-right: 20px;
   opacity: 0.5;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(".menu-arrow").on("click", function () {

if ($(".menu-slide").css("display") === "none") {

    $(".menu-slide").css("display", "block");
    $(".menu-slide").animate({
        right: 0
    });
    $(".menu-arrow").animate({
        right: $(".menu-slide").css("width")
    }, function () {
        $(".menu-arrow").removeClass("fa-angle-left");
        $(".menu-arrow").addClass("fa-angle-right");
    });

} else {

    $(".menu-slide").animate({
        right: '-40vw'
    }, function () {
        $(".menu-slide").css("display", "none");
    });
    $(".menu-arrow").animate({
        right: 0
    }, function () {
        $(".menu-arrow").removeClass("fa-angle-right");
        $(".menu-arrow").addClass("fa-angle-left");
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Can you share a working url?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://joaoandreossi.github.io/

Comment: can't replicate on my android device.